# /data/system/packages.xml does not update after install/uninstall of apps. Is that expected?

Tags: custom-roms, installation, rom, system-apps

I am using a android board with a custom ROM based on Android 4.4.2. I was trying to override a /system/priv-app/ app by installing an updated version in normal partition.

While testing I realised that the override only stays till reboot.So I started digging into AOSP source which is when I came across the call to [`disableSystemPackageLPw`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/Settings.java#L458) which in turn calls [`writeLPr`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/Settings.java#L2373).

If `writeLPr` goes through I expect to see my package listed in the "/data/system/packages.xml" file. However that is not the case here and hence I suspect that to be the root cause.

It would be great to know view on expected usage of packages.xml from the community users to confirm the same.

Comment: i don't believe this. where does system get old apk from after you replaced?

Comment: As @alecxs said that should not happen because the new apk is immediately saved to `/data/app` on update. Settings might be cached for some time. Try clearing app's data after update. Or force write `pm`'s cached data: `dumpsys package write`.

Comment: @alecxs The old apk is still in /system/priv-app. Based on what I read in PackageManager scan code. It scans the files system for paths /system/priv-app, /system/app, /vendor/app and /data/app for registering installed packages after boot. Since system/priv-app gets scanned first the old apk gets the oackage registered and the apk in /data is treated as duplicate. I get a log saying Skipping duplicate package in logcat  from "PackageManager" tag,

Comment: @IrfanLatif I tried out another android board. There I could verify that packages.xml had two entries for my package; one with tag <updated-package> and another with <package>. On this android board my update is retained after boot as expected. And I also do not see the Skipping Duplicate log. So overall I have come to a conclusion it is ROM specific problem.

Comment: i misread question. thought you did overwrite apk in /system/priv-app

Comment: the duplicate may caused by different apk signature

Comment: @alecxs I was able to get through to the person maintaining the ROM. packages.xml not having that entry was the root cause. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per stock android code. (AOSP) packages.xml needs to have the entry for installed packages for retaining any fancy priv-app kind of configuration/overrides/updates that we do.